# What is the difference between "is" and "are"?

Tags: differences

When I'am writing a paper, I did not know what is the difference between *"is"* and *"are"*?

Should I write:

> "DNA **is** a part of....."

instead of:

> "DNA **are** a part of....."?

I think that plurals can use with "is" or "are", but when I googled and googled, it can only use "is" with singles, and can only use "are" with plurals.

Comment: Why do you think DNA is plural?

Comment: Because there are many dnas.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Deoxyribonucleic acid (DNA) **is** a thread-like chain of nucleotides carrying the genetic instructions used in the growth, development, functioning and reproduction of all known living organisms and many viruses. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA)

Comment: Thanks, I'am mistakenly think dnas are plural. I will edit it.

Comment: The critical question is whether DNA is a "countable noun". Any noun that is non-countable e.g. water, air, sand etc is treated as singular. Hence, unless, you are speaking about several different types of DNA - my suggestion is that it takes a singular verb.

Comment: I edited and please do not warn me again.

Comment: Nitrogen is/are the major constituent of Earth's atmosphere.

Comment: @HotLicks In your sentence, you should use "is" in your sentence, because you did not put "s" in "nitrogen".

Comment: @HotLicks Is that an example?

Comment: Another time please do some research of your own before asking this sort of question (or post on English Language learners). A simple Google search of "DNA is" and "DNA are" will tell you what the usage is. If you are in science you need to learn how to make better use of the resources of the Internet.

Comment: I have googled and googled but I can't really see more information about this question. It is just a link to this question and other questions. A youtube should be more than 8 minutes for a complete usage.

Comment: ??? Who mentioned Youtube?

Comment: :-( Do not mention it. I'am just saying a video should be more than 8 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the main difference between “is” and “are” is that “is” is singular while “are” is plural. This means a singular subject would be paired with the singular verb “is.” As an example,

> The man is a member of the circus performing tonight.

Additionally, “are” is plural, so it must be paired with a plural subject.
As an example,

> The sailors are currently hungry since they are running out of food.

Because of this, you would use “are” in your provided sentence because “DNAs” is plural. However, DNA is usually not mentioned in the plural form unless you are talking about multiple different types of DNAs in multiple different beings. Example: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17125740

Note: If you ever decide to change the subject of your sentence to simply “DNA,” then use “is” instead of “are.”

Comment: Water is a component of every human body. Would you use 'waters' when describing the water in a number of individuals, even considering that the composition (the deuterium content) is different in every case ?

Comment: @NigelJ I have no idea why the OP used DNAs in his sentence, but I took a look at the .gov article I provided, and I realized that they used “DNAs” when talking about crossing DNA from different human bodies. However, I certainly agree with you in that “DNAs” is likely not the correct usage here.

Comment: Yes, agreed. In that case they use the expression 'multiple DNAs' which I agree makes sense in that particular context.

Comment: DNA is not plural. Any chemists would never say "DNAs". I understand.